# LINQ Count() until, is this more efficient?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, ienumerable, micro-optimization

Say I want to check whether there are at least N elements in a collection.

Is this better than doing?

`Count() >= N`

Using:

```
    public static bool AtLeast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int max)
    {
        int count = 0;
        return enumerable.Any(item => ++count >= max);
    }
```

Or even

```
    public static bool Equals<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int amount)
    {
        return enumerable.Take(amount).Count() == amount;
    }
```

How could I benchmark this?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns whether the enumerable has at least the provided amount of elements.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool HasAtLeast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int amount)
    {
        return enumerable.Take(amount).Count() == amount;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns whether the enumerable has at most the provided amount of elements.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool HasAtMost<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int amount)
    {
        return enumerable.Take(amount + 1).Count() <= amount;
    }
```

Comment: _How could I benchmark this?_ - Put the code you'd normally use to invoke them in a loop with timing...

Comment: another option:
enumerable.Select((o, idx) => idx).Any(i => i >= max);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some well-documented optimizations built in to the `.Count()` method. Specifically, if your enumerable is an `ICollection`, `.Count()` will be a constant-time operation as it will use the `ICollection`'s `.Count` property.

However, in the general case it will iterate the entire `IEnumerable` to get the count. If you do not have an `ICollection`, you'd be better off using either of your two suggested methods when there are more than N elements. For the relative performance of those two, you'd have to profile them as others have suggested.

Comment: I'd be wary about his implementations. Are we guaranteed that any Linq methods will be thread safe with writing into an external variable like that? If it traverses the `IEnumerable<T>` sequentially it should be fine. But if at any time it's possible to have multiple threads evaluating that in parallel, that may be ill defined.

Comment: @Mike: At a minimum I'd think the `.Take(n)` approach would be fine - after all, it's just iterating the enumerable and stopping after `n` elements have been reached or the entire collection has been iterated (if there are fewer than `n` elements in the `IEnumerable`). I'm not sure about the thread safety of the `.Any()` approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
        var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000);
        var t = new Stopwatch();

        t.Restart();
        var count = list.Count() > 100000;
        t.Stop();
        PrintTime(t, count);

        t.Restart();
        var atLeast = list.AtLeast(100000);
        t.Stop();
        PrintTime(t, atLeast);

        t.Restart();
        var equals = list.Equalss(100000);
        t.Stop();
        PrintTime(t, equals);
```

Results where PrintTime() prints out the timer ticks:

```
True 20818
True 8774
True 8688
```

Comment: this doesn't even make sense, using a list you know for a fact that the `Count` is 100000, and don't need to invoke any methods. What are your resulsts with using just enumerable.range, without the list?

Comment: Nico, good point :) Updated answer to reflect results using just Enumerable.Range.

Comment: Add a .ToList() to the end of that Enumerable.Range and your list.Count() operation will be the best.